# How to weaken strongly linked symbols in a mach-o static library?

Tags: ios, linker, mach-o

Our app supports iOS5 however one of our 3rd party static libraries has started strongly linking against iOS6 symbols in `UIKit`. I'd like to change this linkage to weak and disable the library on iOS5 (assuming the library doesn't use the symbols in `load`).

I'm looking for something like what I imagine `objcopy --weaken-symbol` from linux does, so does anyone know of any likely tools or will this involve learning the `mach-o` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm none the wiser on mach-o, but I realised that static libraries can't actually decide on *how* they link against *my* frameworks. Only I can do that.

So I went into `Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries` and set `UIKit` to Optional. Now the app launches on iOS5 and I can simply (I think!) not call the offending library.

I'm only slightly disappointed I didn't get to write a re-linking tool